# Check for range of values in MySql database and return if empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

This is my first question on this forum. I need to create a code that will accept a range of values from x to y (area codes) and check for them in the database. If the code is in the database it will return it, and when it is not in the database then it would return the value and an error. I hope that I am making clear as to what I need to do!

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
     public static function uncountedAreaReport($stocktake_id, $sections,$start,$finish)
     {
        if ($start<=$finish) {
    $area_qry = "
      SELECT
          sa.area_code,
          sa.stocktake_area_id,
          ss.stocktake_staff_name
      FROM
          stocktake_areas sa
      LEFT JOIN
          stocktake_staff ss
      ON
          ss.stocktake_staff_id = sa.area_checked_user_id                    
      WHERE
          sa.stocktake_id = '{$stocktake_id}'
      AND
          sa.area_code
              BETWEEN ".$start." AND ".$finish."
                ORDER BY sa.area_code ASC;
  ";

    $area_res = db::c()->query($area_qry);
    $report = "
      <table cellspacing='0' class='area_sum_report'>
              <tr>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:30%;'><div class='nosplit'>Area Name</div></td>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:10%;'><div class='nosplit'>Area Code</div></td>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:14%;'><div class='nosplit'>Area Status</div></td>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:12%;'><div class='nosplit'>Total Count</div></td>                        
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:8%;'><div class='nosplit'>Checked</div></td>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:13%;'><div class='nosplit'>Checked Date</div></td>
                  <td class='simple_header' style='width:13%;'><div class='nosplit'>Checked By</div></td>
              </tr>
  ";
   $st_data = $area_res->fetchAll();
   foreach ($st_data as $stmem){




        $report .= "
          <tr>
          <td style='text-align:left;'><div class='nosplit'>".$start."</div></td>
          <td><div class='nosplit'>".$stmem['area_code']."</div></td>
          <td><div class='nosplit'>".$row['area_status']."</div></td>
          <td><div class='nosplit'>".$rounded_qty."</div></td>                        
          <td><div class='nosplit'>
      ";

           $start++;

        $report .= "
          </div></td>
              <td><div class='nosplit'>".l::datetime($row['area_checked_date'])."</div></td>
              <td><div class='nosplit'>".$row['stocktake_staff_name']."</div></td>
              </tr>
      ";

        $report .= "</table><br/><br/>";

        return $report; 
}       

}}
```

Right now it returns the value if it is in the database, but skips when not. Any suggestions are welcome!

Regards,
Artur

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "return the value and error"?  Shouldn't you do this in the application and not in the database?

Comment: I have a column named area_code in the database. What I need is the following 
if $start IN area_code return YES
if $start NOT IN area_code return NO

this is just simple explanation.

Comment: It sounds like your SQL query is working, you just need to work on the presentation layer (i.e., PHP). What does $st_data contain when the area code is not in the database? (vs. what does $st_data contain when the area code is in the database)

Comment: So you basically just want to check the number of returned rows before the foreach, and if it is 0, you want to state "whoa! That code was not found!" ?

Comment: I need to check if a row was returned for each value between $start and $finish, not a total number of returned rows.

Comment: SQL cannot generate rows that don't exist.  Do you have a table with all the area codes between `$start` and `$finish`?

Comment: I don't at the moment. I could create one with values from 0001 to 4999 as those are all area codes that would be used as far as I'm aware. 

Is there no way in sql to check if anything was returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of logic I would use to rework your php code.

1. Call the same SQL statement
2. Don't use the fetchall
3. Don't use the for loop *(as you had been using it)*.
4. Instead use **fetch** to read 1 row at a time
5. Use a loop that iterates from *start* to *finish*
6. Does the iterated value equal the fetched value?

   1. Yes

      1. Output that the value was found
      2. fetch next row
   2. No

      1. Output the value wasn't found
7. Start the loop over for the next iterated value

Comment: This sounds like something that will work for me. I am not quite sure how to fetch one row at a time AND compare it to the iterated value. 
Right now I have this:
$row = db::c()->query($area_qry);
 while ($row1 = $row->fetchColumn())    {
 
 if($row1 == $start )
 {
  echo $start;
  echo $row1.'<br />';
  $status = 'Success!'.'<br />';
  echo $status;
  
  $start++;
  
  }
 else 
 {
 echo $start.'<br />';
    echo $row1.'<br />';
 echo 'NOPE!'.'<br />';
 break;
 }

Can you give me a start off point regarding fetching one row at a time. Thanks a lot and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a single value, you can get this by counting the matching rows and doing some logic:

```
  SELECT (case when count(*) > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as DoesItExist
  FROM stocktake_areas sa LEFT JOIN
       stocktake_staff ss
       ON ss.stocktake_staff_id = sa.area_checked_user_id                    
  WHERE sa.stocktake_id = '{$stocktake_id}' AND
        sa.area_code BETWEEN ".$start." AND ".$finish."
```

Comment: This almost works for me but I need to do this for EACH number between $start and $finish